# Find objects in the list with the same fields

Tags: java, spring, arraylist, collections, stream

Have a problem to find a best way to find an objects in the list where we have a field with the same values.

For example I have an object

```
public class User {

    private String name;
    private String countryCode;
    private String info;
    private String code;

}
```

In my case a have a lot of objects in list. Some of them have same values.
If I have same 'code' values or more than 2 others (e.g. 'name' and 'countryCode') I need to save them.

Like if I have

```
User user1 = new User("1","DE","1234","BAD");
User user2 = new User("2","FR","4567","GOOD");
User user3 = new User("3","PL","5647","BAD");
```

I need to save user1 and user3

Or if I have

```
User user1 = new User("1","DE","1234","BAD");
User user2 = new User("2","FR","4567","GOOD");
User user3 = new User("3","DE","1234","SOSO");
```

I need to save user1 and user3.
So I need to cover this to cases.

Thank you everyone in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could try defining a compare method that iterates through each variable for the User class and returns true if they are identical or false if they are different. For example:

```
class User{
    int[] variables;
    boolean compare(User othUser){
        for( int i = 0; i < variables.length; i++){
            if(variables[i] == othUser.variables[i]) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then simply user1.compare(user2) would return the values you are looking for.

If your variables are not stored in an array you could simply call each one individually for an identical output and run time.

For more information the Comparator and Comparable interfaces are a great stepping off point.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The example uses `String` objects to hold the user data. For `String` or other reference types, it would be safer to assume two Objects that have the same contents do not necessarily refer to the same Object. So, it would be safer to use  `if (variables[i].equals(othUser.variables[i]))`. In the case of `String`, `.equalsIgnoreCase` could be used.